# Embedding Executable Java (or exe) files into HTML (or php)

Tags: java, php, html, embed, executable-jar

Basically I want to embed the executable jar file of "Catacomb Snatch" [new Mojang game] into my html webpage. I've looked around but I can't seem to find much information on this.

If it would make it easier I could even us a mixture of php[instead of html] and an exe [instead of java]to actually get it to work on my page.

What is the simplest way to embed the jar or exe file into a html or php page?

Information much appreciated.

Comment: This answer might be of some use to you (if you hadn't seen it already): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531740/how-to-embed-jar-in-html

Comment: By embedding do you mean putting a button that runs the game in a new window, or do you want it as an element within the page?

Comment: It would be impractical to embed an 'exe' into a web page.  Even if it were possible on Windows, it could never work on OS X or *nix.  As an aside, [this blurb](http://www.mojang.com/2012/02/20/how-to-use-the-catacomb-snatch-source-code/#more-1255) suggests it is tricky for developers to get 'up and running' with a simple, non-applet based form of the game.  Given the quirky nature of the initial build, I suspect it is not deployable as an applet at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need [java applet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet) of Catacomb Snatch,try to search if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

There's is no "PHP page" in client side, its just HTML and other client-side technologies like Java-script (that's not related to Java).

Java provides Applets that run inside the browser, but the application needs some changes. You can also deploy it with Java WebStart, that will download the application and run it, along most features, but not in the browser windows.

Answer (score 0):

try using the  tag. like this: `<embed src = "put source here" type ="application/octet-stream">`
application/octet-stream is for an exe file
you may need to put in height and width for the window, also make sure to put this between you 
 tags