# class not found exception java in server?

Tags: java, eclipse, applet

I have a java applet which works in eclipses, and i exported it like this, right click folder, export, export as jar, selected class files and project files and 'src' folder, then press 'next' 'next' and then i pick the main class which is called Main_run, which has a main class but don't have anything in it

```
public class Main_run extends Applet implements Runnable, KeyListener, MouseMotionListener, MouseListener
{

    public static void main (String[] args )
    {

    }
}
```

this is because the applet start with 'init()'

Then I made a html page which has this on it

```
<b><applet code="Desktop.jar/Main_run.class" width="320" height="120"></b>
```

not (<) should be <.

then I added both file, the exported jar file and the index to the server im getting this error

"ClassNotFoundException"

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the question at  [How to embed jar in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531740/how-to-embed-jar-in-html).

In other words, use `<applet archive="Desktop.jar" code="Main_run.class" width="320" height="120">`. That's my thought on the subject.